# Cannot fetch images by setting State

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to display my pics by setting the const **[pics, setPics] = useState([])**. In the searchPhotos function, i don't know how to set the state of **setPics** to the result that i got from the API key. I had the error: "'**response' is not defined no-undef**". Please help me to fix my problem! Thank you so much!

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { createApi } from "unsplash-js";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);

  const unsplash = createApi({
    accessKey: "//my config"
  });

  const searchPhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    unsplash.search
      .getPhotos({
        query: query
      })
      .then((results) => {
        setPics(response.results);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={searchPhotos}>
        <label className="label" htmlFor="query">
          {" "}
          {" "}
        </label>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="query"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          className="input"
          placeholder={`Try "dog" or "apple"`}
        />{" "}
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Search{" "}
        </button>{" "}
      </form>
      <div className="card-list">
        {" "}
        {pics.map((pic) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={pic.id}>
              <img
                className="card--image"
                alt={pic.alt_description}
                src={pic.urls.full}
                width="50%"
                height="50%"
              ></img>{" "}
            </div>
          );
        })}{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Sandbox link for better observation: https://codesandbox.io/s/unsplash-search-oshcc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can see an error: OAuth error: The access token is invalid

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
.then((results) => {
   setPics(response.results);
});
...
```

In here, you are passing `results` but trying to set `response` which does not exist. Change this to something like that:

```js
...
.then((results) => {
   setPics(results?.response?.results || []); // from your image
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this & succeed-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { createApi } from "unsplash-js";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);

  const unsplash = createApi({
    accessKey: "Yme6ZcumIXpWryQ0DPc249CE0ua2Mxh66Y-4W2gPAAc"
  });

  const searchPhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    unsplash.search
      .getPhotos({
        query: query
      })
      .then((results) => {
        setPics(results.response.results);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={searchPhotos}>
        <label className="label" htmlFor="query">
          {" "}
          {" "}
        </label>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="query"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          className="input"
          placeholder={`Try "dog" or "apple"`}
        />{" "}
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Search{" "}
        </button>{" "}
      </form>
      <div className="card-list">
        {" "}
        {pics.map((pic) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={pic.id}>
              <img
                className="card--image"
                alt={pic.alt_description}
                src={pic.urls.full}
                width="50%"
                height="50%"
              ></img>{" "}
            </div>
          );
        })}{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Result screenshot: https://ibb.co/J7BKXSQ